# How to connect jhipster on aws to elk cloud

Tags: jhipster, elastic-stack

I need to connect my [JHIPSTER](https://www.jhipster.tech/) app that is in AWS / elasticbeanstalk to ELK Cloud.

It does not work with this:

```
jhipster:
     logging:
         logstash:
             enabled: true
             host: localhost # If using a Virtual Machine on Mac OS X or Windows with docker-machine, use the Docker's host IP here
             port: 5000
             queueSize: 512
```

as reference https://www.jhipster.tech/monitoring/

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you have to connect to logstash. Jhipster delivers a format to send it to a logstash service. Which in turn transfers it to elasticsearch -> Kibana.